# Warning: Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced by REPLACEMENT CHARACTER

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm creating a script to download some mp3 podcasts from a site and write them to a certain location. I'm nearly finished, and the files are being downloaded and created. However, I'm running into a problem where the binary data can't be fully decoded and the mp3 files won't play.

Here's my code:

```
import re
import os
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

def getHTMLstring(url):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    soupString = soup.encode('utf-8')
    return soupString

def getList(html_string):
    urlList = re.findall('(http://podcast\.travelsinamathematicalworld\.co\.uk\/mp3/.*\.mp3)', html_string)
    firstUrl = urlList[0]
    finalList = [firstUrl]

    for url in urlList:
        if url != finalList[0]:
            finalList.insert(0,url)

    return finalList

def getBinary(netLocation):
    req = urllib2.urlopen(netLocation)
    reqSoup = BeautifulSoup(req)
    reqString = reqSoup.encode('utf-8')
    return reqString

def getFilename(string):
    splitTerms = string.split('/')
    fileName = splitTerms[-1]
    return fileName

def writeFile(sourceBinary, fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'wb') as fp:
        fp.write(sourceBinary)



def main():
    htmlString = getHTMLstring('http://www.travelsinamathematicalworld.co.uk')
    urlList = getList(htmlString)

    fileFolder = 'D:\\Dropbox\\Mathematics\\Travels in a Mathematical World\\Podcasts'
    os.chdir(fileFolder)

    for url in urlList:
        name = getFilename(url)
        binary = getBinary(url)
        writeFile(binary, name)
        time.sleep(2)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run the code, I get the following warning in my console:

WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

I'm thinking that it has to do with the fact that the data that I'm using is encoded in UTF-8, and maybe the write method expects a different encoding? I'm new to Python (and really to programming in general), and I'm stuck.

Comment: Show us your trackback and tell us where the error exactly occurs. And then figure out the offending string using pdb or debug messages causing the problem.

Comment: By traceback, do you mean the error messages that pop up in the console? If so, that was the problem... the program was running normally and creating the files, so it didn't seem like the there was anything wrong. The only text that printed to the console was the warning that I listed in my original post.

Comment: Yes that is the traceback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to download some mp3 files from urls. 
You can retrieve those urls via `BeautifulSoup`. But you don't need to use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the urls. You just need to save it directly.
For example,

```
url = 'http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P96/P96-1004.pdf'
res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
with open(fileName, 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(res.read())
```

If I use `BeautifulSoup` to parse that pdf url

```
reqSoup = BeautifulSoup('http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P96/P96-1004.pdf')
```

`reqSoup` is not the pdf file, but a HTML response. Actually, it is

```
<html><body><p>http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P96/P96-1004.pdf</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Ahhh, this works. I'm not sure what made me think that I had to create a string out of the binary itself. Thank you!!