# How to get rid off the "WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER." in beautifulSoup python3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Using pydev, while compiling this code:

```
import re
import urllib.request 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://talkingpointsmemo.com/news/trump-response-melania-speech-plagiarism"
req = urllib.request.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/51.0.2704.103'})
html = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
```

giving the error `WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.`

This is not working.

```
reqSoup = BeautifulSoup('http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P96/P96-1004.pdf')
```

Source:  [Warning: Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced by REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038402/warning-some-characters-could-not-be-decoded-and-were-replaced-by-replacement)
and what is `html_path` in this line

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(html_path, 'r'),"html.parser",from_encoding="iso-8859-1")
```

Source : [WARNING:root:Some characters could not be decoded, and were replaced with REPLACEMENT CHARACTER. With Requests and Beastuifulsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110289/warningrootsome-characters-could-not-be-decoded-and-were-replaced-with-replac)

Comment: what do you think `BeautifulSoup('http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/P/P96/P96-1004.pdf')` is going to do?

Comment: Also the html is utf-8 encoded not iso-8859-1

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. I just read that from the given source.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How can I get rid off the mentioned error?